# MAXSCRIPT error with multiple If expressions

Tags: max, maxscript

I've started learning Maxscripts and i've now hit a wall, 
im trying to get the name of my selection, if it's a single object and 
then if its more than 1, have the label display the number of objects as a string.

but i keep getting an error... any idea?

```
group "Current Selection:" 
(
label lbl_01 "Nothing Selected"
)
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------// Current Selection Function

```
fn letmeknow obj= 

(       
    local contador = (selection.count as string)

    if selection.count != 0 then  
    (

        lbl_01.text = ("Name: " + obj.name) 

    )
    else 
    (
        lbl_01.text = "Nothing Selected" 
    )
    if selection.count >= 2 do (lbl_01.text = ("Objects: " + contador))
)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is outside the code you've supplied and without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to tell. Anyway, here's a working example using case expression instead of multiple ifs:

```
rollout test "Test"
(
    group "Current Selection:" 
    (
        label lbl_01 "Nothing Selected"
    )
    button btnTest "Test"

    fn getSelectionString = 
    (
        case selection.count of
        (
            0 : "Nothing Selected"
            1 : "Name: " + selection[1].name
            default : "Objects: " + selection.count as string
        )
    )

    on btnTest pressed do
        lbl_01.text = getSelectionString()
)
createDialog test
```